# Add input into list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, input, collections

I'm trying to add user's input into list and then show it in reverse order. The elements are added until the user enters 0. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputInArrrayList{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = s.nextInt();
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        while(a > 0) {
            myList.add(a);
            if (a == 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        Collections.reverse(myList);
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

But the loop doesn't break when it's 0. Instead, it throws OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap space. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are only reading one input (before the loop).

Comment: And then going into an infinite loop if it's greater than 0

Comment: Try to execute your code in your mind. Example: the user inputs `5`. `5 > 0` so you get into the while loop. You add `5` to the list. `5 != 0` so the while does not break. You check the loop condition again and surprise, `5` is still greater than `0`. It is added again in the list. No break. Another loop cycle. Do you see the problem? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct your loop

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
while(true) {
    int a = s.nextInt();
    if (a == 0){
        break;
    }  else
        myList.add(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

at least one a >= 0  needed for break to execute:

```
   while(a >= 0) {
        myList.add(a);
        if (a == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the below code:

```
while(a > 0) {
    myList.add(a);
    if (a == 0){
        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see after reading the first user input and assigning it to `a`, the the while loop is running infinitely. This happens because the condition argument   which is the `a` variable never changes.
So you have to insert the part of code that updates that variable inside the while loop. Below is a simple fix:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = 1;
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
while(a > 0) {
    a = s.nextInt();
    if (a == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        myList.add(a);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently , you are getting into an infinite loop as a gets set to the first number and then keeps looping, thus, keeps adding same number to the list.
you need to add inside the while loop.
int a = s.nextInt();